# How to limit the datepicker for a single text box

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to limit the values of datepicker for a single text box. The start and end dates are from other textboxes. I found the way in web. But it is not able to limit the values.Any help?

```
$(function() {
    var pickerOpts={
            minDate:$("#from").val(),
            maxDate:$("#to").val()
    };

    $( "#plan_date" ).datepicker(pickerOpts);  
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the values you fetch from the other elements are conform to the `dateFormat` option of the widget?

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi yes I am sure about that because in those two text boxes I mean #from,#to I used datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that the values in `$("#from").val()` and `$("#to").val()` are conform to the `dateFormat` (as Frederic asked in the comment), give this a try (worked for me a couple of months ago)

`$(function() {
    $("#plan_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#from").val());
    $("#plan_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#to").val());
});`

Comment: No,this time it doesnot even show up.The datepicker is not visible now.

Comment: you should also initialize it. so do `$("#plan_date").datepicker()` and then the code i posted

Answer (score 0):

As per jquery Date picker minDate property you can set minDate and max date for the field

[Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Get the values from test boxes and place it into respected opsitions. But you need to do some of the background works to set the dates into functions as below format

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) );
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+1m +1w" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `datepicker` widget in your other input fields, you should use their `onClose` property to manage the `minDate` and `maxDate` of your **plan_date** `datepicker`.

```js
$.datepicker({
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        // do something with the selectedDate
    }
});
```

Here is a full example of what I mean... It's not pretty (didn't bother with a stylesheet), but it accomplishes what I believe you're trying to do, in a more intuitive way then later grabbing the values of the other input fields.

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#start").datepicker({
                    onClose: function(date) {
                        $("#end").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
                        $("#range").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
                    }
                });
                $("#end").datepicker({
                    onClose: function(date) {
                        $("#start").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
                        $("#range").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
                    }
                });
                $("#range").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="start"></p>
            <p>End Date: <input type="text" id="end"></p>
            <p>Date Range: <input type="text" id="range"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No dear, I need to pick those values from text boxes. There is some dependency. Please tell me how to do it according to the problem statement.